# Using Date or Long type in geomesa accumulo for storing timestamp value

Tags: indexing, geomesa

I am using geomesa for indexing over acccumulo storage. I have an attribute which stores timestamp values. I am confused between which TYPE and INDEX to use for storing timestamp values depending upon index performance.

There are two cases

1. Using `Long` as timestamp type and create attribute index.
2. Using `Date` type and use default date index.

I want to know which technique is better out of this two in terms of searching and sorting in millions of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geomesa indexing is optimized for the second case, `Date` type with default date. The Z3 and XZ3 indices are designed to combine the default date and default geometry into a composite index for fast geospatial queries.

Examples:

[GDELT feature type configuration](https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/master/geomesa-tools/conf/sfts/gdelt/reference.conf#L33)

[T-Drive feature type configuration](https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/master/geomesa-tools/conf/sfts/tdrive/reference.conf#L6)

[Twitter feature type configuration](https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/master/geomesa-tools/conf/sfts/twitter/reference.conf#L27)

One note, you can have multiple `Date` attributes and the `default` key in the feature type serves to say which attribute to put in the indices.